# How to style child component only?

Tags: css, angular

I am working on code that involves a parent component with several child components. I am trying to move filter icon down 5 pixels on one of the child components. The problem is that no matter what CSS I write in the child component, it doesn't affect the child component. If I put the following code in the parent component, it works on the child component, but unfortunately affects other components as well:

```
:host /deep/ svg-icon.filterIcon {
  height: 22px !important;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}
```

If I put this same code in the child I want to style, nothing happens.  Neither does anything happen when I use the following code:

```
svg-icon.filterIcon {
  height: 22px !important;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}
```

How to style this one child only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming the child component inside the parent component's CSS worked, as follows:

```
 :host /deep/ app-milestones-summary svg-icon.filterIcon {
  height: 22px !important;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}
```

I still don't understand how to style the child component directly, but I'm glad I found something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ViewEncapsulation` in your child component:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core'; //Import this

@Component({
   moduleId: id,
   selector: 'my-child',
   templateUrl: 'my-child.component.html',
   styles: [`
     .your_css_class {
        background: red;
      }
   `],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // put this
 })

 class ChildComponent {
    @Input() some_data: string;
 }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried to do a hard refresh in your browser? Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: The hard refresh didn't work.  I found an answer, below.